# How does trees know to balance themselves so that they never fall down

Tags: botany, plant-anatomy, bio-mechanics

Well i was flying kites today I saw a tree and its branches were spread around in random directions... I would like to know that how do these trees know to nourish their branches in some direction so as it doesn't fall off due to gravity. I know it can get its strength from the roots inside the soil so that it does not fall. But if this strength were not enough the tree may fall due to weight of its own branches. Can this happen??

I am new to this site I don't know much about the rules here. Feel free to edit if I have done any mistakes(especially about tags)

Comment: tree's do fall down, there may be a benefit, in terms of stability, to growing in a more "balanced" spread of branches but other factors also influence the direction the branches grow e.g. prevailing sun and wind conditions

Comment: I think the strength of the tree's roots are more of a factor in holding it up than the symmetry of its branches